# How can i import and read bookmarks of MS word in to Java

Tags: java, api, ms-word, bookmarks

It's a very hard question and I searched for it and I didn't find any good answer!
I want to read (key) Bookmarks of Ms Word and set the vlaue in Word with Java program language! how can I do it?
with Apache POI didn't work! :(
thanks

Comment: should you realy do this in java? .Net is look like much more reasonable. Can you write small project in c#, and (if required) - call its exe from java?

Comment: I should do it in Java! unfortunately!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've found the solution, and wrote the program.
this link maybe help you! http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-read-the-value-of-bookmarks-docx-td5710184.html
but it's just for new Ms Word (.docx)
For old version (.doc) I wrote a method by my self but it didn't work correctly.
for old version we should use **org.apache.poi.hwpf** but for new version **org.apache.poi.xwpf**!
and for controlling Ms Word or MS Office we should use **Jacob Project**.
If you have questions you can ask me again

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with docx4j.

The challenge is that bookmarks are point tags which surround arbitrary content.

So if your intent is to replace the content of a bookmark, you'd be better off considering an alternative approach.

See [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/plutext/document-generation-2012osdcsydney) for suggestions.